# Java not working properly after making changes to the environment. How to undo the changes?

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, jvm

I made this change from terminal in Ubuntu and now java is not working. Also, I am not able to launch eclipse (which may be related to the change)

> java -agentlib:TakipiAgent
>
> java -agentpath:/opt/takipi/lib/libTakipiAgent.so

The error that I got after doing `java -version`

> Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentlib:TakipiAgent
> Error occurred during initialization of VM
> Could not find agent library TakipiAgent on the library path, with error: libTakipiAgent.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I want to remove this option now and set the default what it was before. I tried making change in /etc/environment but that did not work.

Due to this, eclipse is also not working.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: try [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) Erasing environment variables. BTW What have you tried? Have you exit the console? Have you tried to reboot?

Comment: I have removed it from /etc/environment. But that also did not work. So I just added JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="" in my bashrc file. Now its working. But I still get this message:

picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to just get eclipse working again you can do a full uninstall and reinstall of the jvm using synaptic software manager. That should clear out the agentlib that you set.

Regarding that agent, have you verified that it exists in that dir? You may want to verify your library path as well since that may ultimately be what matters. Maybe move that library to an existing known library path.